# how to see all the topic that we created in kafka on the windows

Tags: windows, apache-kafka

I want to see all the topic which I created in the Kafka. I used this command to get all the topics but it doesn't work.

```sh
bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181
```

Comment: Can you mention the error you got? And what is the zookeeper host name?

Comment: the terminal doesn't show anything. the terminal popo up a bash window. after that, the window also disappears.  after that, the terminal gets terminated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem. I did run it with `kafka-topics.bat` file in Windows directory inside of the bin folder of Kafka.

```sh
kafka-topics.bat --list --zookeeper localhost:2181
```